# Which custom data labeling or scoring method for the test set is correct and why?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, training-data, sentence

Let's say I have some documents belonging to both train and test sets and I have respective ground truth for these documents (0/1).

Consider a scenario where I intend to do a deep learning sentence regression experiment. If I extract all individual sentences from all the documents in both train and test sets, I would not have a ground truth at the "sentence-level". To assign a target value/ground truth estimate/numerical score (to perform the regression) for sentences belonging to the train set, I devised a method where I utilized the first n words from a **train SHAP beeswarm summary plot** obtained in a prior classification experiment at the document-level.
To clarify, this method first checks if an individual sentence (from the train set of documents) belongs to a 0 or 1 class (recall that I have the ground truth for all documents at the document level). If it belongs to a 0 document, then the scoring mechanism uses the first n words from the train SHAP plot in one way and if it belongs to a 1 document then the scoring mechanism uses the first n words from the train SHAP plot in a different way.

How do I assign a numerical score to sentences belonging to the test set? My performance evaluation objective or metric is the MAE which requires a comparison between target scores and predicted scores.

1. Do I mirror the same scoring mechanism that was applied for sentences in the train set? i.e. first checking if a sentence in the test set belongs to 0 or 1 and then use the first n words from the **train SHAP plot** itself to assign a target estimate?
2. Or do I not check if a sentence belongs to 0 or 1 and use the the first n words from the **train SHAP plot** in a generic, uniform fashion?

Which method is right/correct/appropriate ? I guess both methods are *not wrong* and I also guess one should not use the test SHAP plot. My goal is to avoid data leakage whatsoever.